# Create a mask to bigger Image using another smaller image with transparency

Tags: java, android, graphics, xfermode

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 1]

[image: Result]

I have two Images. Image 1 is big and only has some colors. Image 2 has vector numbers in black color with transparent background. I am trying to color Image 2 letters using Image 1 colors. I have tried using .svg then converting to bitmap.

I have tried creating my very own CustomImage (which overrides View). I am also overriding OnDraw, to draw the bitmaps and using PorterDuffXerMode to create the mask in real time.

I expect to get the colored sevens, without the black background or the rest of the image on the right side.

This is image 1 ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha1lN.png

This is image 2---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQrme.png

Result---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/atJYF.jpg

```css
<vector android:height="93dp" android:viewportHeight="93"
    android:viewportWidth="318.97" android:width="319dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#010101" android:pathData="M0,0l0.7,11.51l41.97,0l-38.08,67.92l9.59,6.19l49.54,-85.62l-63.72,0l63.72,0"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#010101" android:pathData="M255.25,0l0.71,11.51l41.96,0l-38.08,67.92l9.59,6.19l49.54,-85.62l-63.72,0l63.72,0"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#010101" android:pathData="M191.32,0l0.71,11.51l41.96,0l-38.08,67.92l9.59,6.19l49.55,-85.62l-63.73,0l63.73,0"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#010101" android:pathData="M127.6,0l0.71,11.51l41.96,0l-38.08,67.92l9.59,6.19l49.54,-85.62l-63.72,0l63.72,0"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#010101" android:pathData="M63.88,0l0.7,11.51l41.97,0l-38.08,67.92l9.59,6.19l49.54,-85.62l-63.72,0l63.72,0"/>
</vector>
```

```css
<vector android:height="93dp" android:viewportHeight="93"
    android:viewportWidth="797.67" android:width="798dp"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:pathData="M0.5,0.5h796.67v92h-796.67z"
        android:strokeColor="#000" android:strokeWidth="1">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="797.17" android:endY="46.5"
                android:startX="0.5" android:startY="46.5" android:type="linear">
                <item android:color="#FFF6B046" android:offset="0"/>
                <item android:color="#FFF870F3" android:offset="0.16"/>
                <item android:color="#FF00D2FE" android:offset="0.37"/>
                <item android:color="#FF00E3CD" android:offset="0.55"/>
                <item android:color="#FFF871F0" android:offset="0.79"/>
                <item android:color="#FFF784BD" android:offset="0.86"/>
                <item android:color="#FFF6AD4E" android:offset="1"/>
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
</vector>

Vectors data:
```

````
    private Bitmap mImage;
    private Bitmap mMask;
    private int posX=0;
    private int posY=0;

    private Paint maskPaint;
    private Paint imagePaint;

    public CustomImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        maskPaint  = new Paint();
        maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));

        imagePaint = new Paint();
        imagePaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();

        mImage = getBitmap(getContext(), R.drawable.colors2);
        mMask = getBitmap(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_black_seven);

        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, maskPaint);
        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, imagePaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mImage, posX, posY, imagePaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mMask, 0, 0, maskPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private static Bitmap getBitmap(VectorDrawable vectorDrawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private static Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, int drawableId) {
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), drawableId);
        } else if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
            return getBitmap((VectorDrawable) drawable);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unsupported drawable type");
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: I dont seem to understand how you intended to confirm that the image2 (7777) is displayed on image1 when having same color as image one without it having a colored background?

Comment: Image 1 is colors. Image2 7777's are colored black with transparent background. All I want to do is color the numbers to the colors of image 1, the problem is that instead of keeping the background transparent it is replacing it with the color black.

Comment: Post the content of `ic_black_seven` and `image1`

Comment: I mean the vector drawable content not screenshot. If they are both png image then post the pngs, again not the screen shots because you already specified that in the link.